# How to iterage through Message content type in Discussion list

Tags: content-type, linq

I need to iterate through all the columns (default + custom) in Message content type in Discussion list.

i have used this code:

```
//select a single discussion (in this case, the first one), to view it's contentDiscussion
topic = (Discussion)dc.TeamDiscussion.Single(t => t.Id == 5);

//Get all the replies for the selected discussion
IEnumerable<Message> replies = 
   from reply in dc.TeamDiscussion.ScopeToFolder("/"+topic.Reply+"/"+topic.Title, false)                               
   select (Message)reply;
```

How can I iterate through the IEnumerable replies?
I do not want to use CAML.

Please Suggest best possible way to get the results through LINQ

Comment: Did you try `foreach (Message reply in replies) { }` ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Discussion list work the following way:

`List.Items` -> Message ContentType

`List.Folders` -> Discussion ContentType

So to get the Replies, search in the `List.Items`.